# How can I get cookies from socket message (PHP)?

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I have a socket chat application script in PHP. I'd like to authenticate the users, but I can't get the cookies from the request headers only at the handshake. This is my script below. How can I get the cookies every time, when the client sends a message? The getallheaders function doesn't working, because it doesn't include the cookies. The socket_recv function gives me only the body of the request.
SocketController doesn't important in this case, it makes only error checking, and it has some field declarations.

```
<?php namespace Models\Messages;
use Controllers\Messages\SocketController;
use Models\Logs\ErrorLog;
use PDO;

class Socket extends SocketController {

    public function SocketHandler() {

        $this->clientSocketArray = [$this->socketResource];

        while (true) {
            $newSocketArray = $this->clientSocketArray;
            socket_select($newSocketArray, $null, $null, 0, 10);
            
            if (in_array($this->socketResource, $newSocketArray)) {
                $newSocket = socket_accept($this->socketResource);
                $this->clientSocketArray[] = $newSocket;
                $header = socket_read($newSocket, 1024);
                $this->DoHandshake($header, $newSocket, self::HOST, self::PORT);
                
                socket_getpeername($newSocket, $client_ip_address);
                $connectionACK = $this->NewConnectionACK($client_ip_address);
                
                $this->Send($connectionACK);
                
                $newSocketIndex = array_search($this->socketResource, $newSocketArray);
                unset($newSocketArray[$newSocketIndex]);
            }
            
            foreach ($newSocketArray as $newSocketArrayResource) {
                //$headers = apache_request_headers();
                $headers = getallheaders();
                file_put_contents("headers.txt", json_encode($headers), FILE_APPEND);

/*//!!!this is the message sender part!!!, I'd like to get the cookies here*/

                while(socket_recv($newSocketArrayResource, $socketData, 1024, 0) >= 1) {

                    $socketMessage = $this->Unseal($socketData);
                    $messageObj = json_decode($socketMessage, 1);

                    $senderID = isset($messageObj["senderID"]) ? (int)$messageObj["senderID"] : 0;
                    $receiverID = isset($messageObj["receiverID"]) ? (int)$messageObj["receiverID"] : 0;
                    $messageType = isset($messageObj["messageType"]) ? (int)$messageObj["messageType"] : 1;
                    $message = isset($messageObj["message"]) ? $messageObj["message"] : "nincs üzenet";
                    
                    $chat_box_message = $this->CreateChatBoxMessage(
                        $senderID, $receiverID, $messageType, $message
                    );

                    $this->Send($chat_box_message);
                    break 2;
                }
                
                $socketData = @socket_read($newSocketArrayResource, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
                if ($socketData === false) {
                    socket_getpeername($newSocketArrayResource, $client_ip_address);
                    $connectionACK = $this->ConnectionDisconnectACK($client_ip_address);
                    $this->Send($connectionACK);
                    $newSocketIndex = array_search($newSocketArrayResource, $this->clientSocketArray);
                    unset($this->clientSocketArray[$newSocketIndex]);
                }
            }
        }

        socket_close($this->socketResource);
    }

    function Send($message) {
        // global $clientSocketArray;
        $messageLength = strlen($message);

        foreach($this->clientSocketArray as $clientSocket) {
            @socket_write($clientSocket, $message, $messageLength);
        }

        return true;
    }

    function Unseal($socketData) {
        $length = ord($socketData[1]) & 127;
        if($length == 126) {
            $masks = substr($socketData, 4, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 8);
        }
        else if($length == 127) {
            $masks = substr($socketData, 10, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 14);
        }
        else {
            $masks = substr($socketData, 2, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 6);
        }
        $socketData = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
            $socketData .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
        }
        return $socketData;
    }

    function Seal($socketData) {
        $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
        $length = strlen($socketData);
        
        if($length <= 125)
            $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
        elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
            $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
        elseif($length >= 65536)
            $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
        return $header.$socketData;
    }

    function DoHandshake($receivedHeader, $clientSocketResource, $hostName, $port) {
        $headers = array();
        $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receivedHeader);
        foreach($lines as $line)
        {
            $line = chop($line);
            if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
            {
                $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
            }
        }

        $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
        $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
        $buffer  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
        "WebSocket-Origin: {$hostName}/maganoktatas\r\n" .
        "WebSocket-Location: ws://$hostName:$port/maganoktatas/app/ajax/sockeg_messages.php\r\n".
        "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
        socket_write($clientSocketResource, $buffer, strlen($buffer));
    }
    
    function NewConnectionACK($clientIP) {
        $message = 'New client ' . $clientIP.' joined';

        $messageArray = [
            "messageType"=>5,
            "message"=>$message
        ];

        $ACK = $this->Seal(json_encode($messageArray));
        return $ACK;
    }
    
    function ConnectionDisconnectACK($clientIP) {
        $message = 'Client ' . $clientIP.' disconnected';

        $messageArray = [
            "messageType"=>5,
            "message"=>$message
        ];
        
        $ACK = $this->Seal(json_encode($messageArray));
        return $ACK;
    }
    
    public function GetUserName(string $friendID):string {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT CONCAT(LastName, ' ' , FirstName) as FullName
        FROM users WHERE UserID = ?");
        $stmt->execute([
            $friendID
        ]);

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return isset($row["FullName"]) ? $row["FullName"] : "";
    }
    
    function CreateChatBoxMessage(int $senderID, int $receiverID, int $messageType, 
    string $message):string {

        $messageArray = [
            "messageType"=>$messageType,
            "message"=>htmlspecialchars($message),
            "receiverID"=>$receiverID,
            "senderID"=>$senderID, 
            "senderName"=>$this->GetUserName($senderID)
        ];

        $chatMessage = $this->Seal(json_encode($messageArray));
        return $chatMessage;
    }

    function __destruct() {
        //
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't and you don't need.
Browser is sending cookie only during hanshake when connection is made by http protocol. After hanshake, the protocol changes from http to websocket. Your client is connected by tcp connection, so when client sends message you already know from who is this message. Simply save your client data (id, login or sth) together with socket handler after acceppting connection.